# How do I find the pgAdmin connection parameters?

Tags: python, arcmap, postgresql, spatial-database, pgadmin-3

I need to create a connection from arcmap to pgadmin using a python module because of an arcpy script, but I am unsure of how to get the pgadmin connection parameters. I think it may be some kind of file in a directory, but I am unsure. This pgadmin database is on a windows machine.

Comment: Do you mean saved connections to postgresql database that you can access with pgadmin. Information about these connections can be found from a pgpass.conf file that is located in %appdata%/postgresql folder when using Windows (winXP: C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\postgresql, win7: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\postgresql).

Comment: You mean to reach postgis table via python?

Comment: yes. Essentially I need to use more complex sql queries to handle duplicates which I do not want to delete buy rather modify and it seems to me that psql would be easier than converting my shapefile to gdb and then back to shapefile to handle this.